# Ruby, How to read an environmental variable that is an array

Tags: ruby, linux, environment-variables, vagrant

I'm working with a Vagrantfile, which is based on Ruby language. I'm trying to read from the environmental variables of the Linux OS. I've created two environmental variables. One is a simple string, the other is an array of strings

```
>$ export SIMPLE=string
>$ export ARRAY=(hello world test)
```

The first, SIMPLE, I can read in just fine from the Vagrantfile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

simpName=  ENV['SIMPLE']

puts simpName
```

output

```
:~/dev/vagrant$ vagrant up
string
```

no issues there, however, when I attempt to read the array, ARRAY, I get a NilClass. there's nothing there.

```
array = ENV['ARRAY']
puts array
puts array.class
```

output

```
NilClass
```

if I read the variable on the command line, I see it just fine.

```
>$ echo ${ARRAY[@]}
```

Output

```
~/dev/vagrant$ echo ${TEST[@]}
hello world test
```

any insight? The worst-case scenario is I pass the array as a single string and split, but I would think this has been done.

UPDATE:
So i pulled all environmental variables into a hash. searched the hash and found that 'TEST' wasn't even there, hence why its returning NilClass. However, I can understand that it might not like the array, but why doesn't it just show me the first value.

Comment: According to ruby's documentation for ENV, it generally works with Strings. In fact, it serializes any object you pass to it, by calling `to_s` on it, for example `ENV["variable"] = SomeObject.new`, will attempt to convert SomeObject to string, and raise error if unable. I am not sure why it returns nil value for ARRAY though

Comment: well, I checked out the documentation and found a to_h option for ENV. Which turns all variables into a hash. I looked through the hash keys and 'TEST' isn't even there. Which is why its Nil

Comment: it appears the easiest solution is just going to be me setting a string value as the env and then splitting it in Ruby

Comment: @StefanRendevski Environmental variables are just strings just like the parameters in HTTP. There is no syntax that works cross platform or even across shells for other types in env vars and if you want to do anything more advanced you need to deserialize it yourself. Thats one of the reasons why Rails uses a URL for database connections.